# A bizarre phenomenon in my java program

Tags: java, gmt, java.util.date

I found a bizarre phenomenon in my java program at runtime, just look at my code:

```
System.out.println(" date " + new Date(1359931355141L).toGMTString() );
```

the output by this statement was "date **3** Feb 2013 22:42:35 GMT",  and

```
System.out.println(" date " + new Date(1359931355141L).getDate() );
```

the output by this was "date **4**" , see, why not **3** here ???

I could not figure out what's wrong with my program; I am doubting whether my JVM ran into bugs.
Guys, would you like to have a test on your JVM for this two statements?

Comment: What is the timezone for the machine you ran this program on?

Comment: Where are you? If time was 22:42 GMT, Spain is GMT+1, but now we are +2 because of summer time, so here that same moment was 00:42 of the next day

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you live east of central Europe (in a timezone that is at least GMT+1.5Hr).

[`getDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29) (which is deprecated btw) returns the *day of the month*, and it's returning `4` (instead of `3`) because in your timezone, that epoch time is already into the next day, whereas in England (GMT) it's still day `3` of the month.

Answer (score 1):

What's your locale? If it's 3 Feb 2013 22:42:35 GMT but your locale is GMT+10 then your local date will be 4. Nothing bizzare at all, this is the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Well. that depends on what your current locale is. GMT will give you time if GMT timezone. getDate will give you time of your locale.